# How to store output of PowerShell command in Azure DevOps Pipeline Output Variable and use it in next stage?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-powershell

Im trying to execute below code from Azure DevOps Pipeline Azure PowerShell task and retrieve the output in Pipeline "Output Variables" and use the output variable as input to the next stage. How to do this? Is the below output array or an object?

```
PS C:\> Get-AzDataFactoryV2IntegrationRuntimeKey -ResourceGroupName 'rg-test-dfv2' -DataFactoryName 'test-df-eu2' -Name 'test-selfhost-ir'

AuthKey1                                                 AuthKey2
--------                                                 --------
IR@89895504-f647-48fd-8dd3-42fa556d67e3******            IR@89895504-f647-48fd-8dd3-42fa556d67e3****
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.datafactory/get-azdatafactoryv2integrationruntimekey?view=azps-5.0.0#outputs) of this command is an object of [`PSIntegrationRuntimeKeys`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.commands.datafactoryv2.models.psintegrationruntimekeys?view=azurerm-ps), to use the output variable as input to the next stage, you could follow this link - [Passing variables from stage to stage in Azure DevOps Release Pipelines](https://stefanstranger.github.io/2019/06/26/PassingVariablesfromStagetoStage/).

**Update:**

You could use the commands below, store the `$authkey1` and `$authkey2` in separate variables.

```
$keys = Get-AzDataFactoryV2IntegrationRuntimeKey -ResourceGroupName <group-name> -DataFactoryName joyfactory -Name integrationRuntime2
$authkey1 = $keys.AuthKey1
$authkey2 = $keys.AuthKey2
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Joy. So how to get the output of the PSIntegrationRuntimeKeys and store it in a single variable so that it can be used as an output variable. How to get each key in separate variables?

Comment: Thanks a lot Joy. I will check this and will see how can I add it to the Pipeline variable.

Comment: @YogeshKulkarni You're welcome, just follow the link I mentioned, it should work.

Comment: I tried for changing the Stage variable value in the script and print it but its not working. Code -- $greeting = "Hello World"

Write-Output -InputObject ('Variable Stagevar in Task 1, Stage 1 is: {0}' -f $Stagevar)

Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Stagevar;isOutput=true]${greeting}"

echo "In Stage 1"
echo "$(Stagevar)"

Comment: Hi @Yogesh Kulkarni, It seems to be another issue, do you mind accepting this answer and raise a new ticket to describe the latest issue? This will help you get better help. Thanks

Comment: Accepted answer. Thanks Joy.